# What is the best way to work with separate svg as background?

Tags: html, svg

I want to achieve this :

[image]

In my code I made it this way:

```
<div id="navigation" class=" container-fluid">
    <img id="left-poly" height="100%" src="img/left-polygon.svg">
    <img id="right-poly" height="50%" src="img/right-polygon.svg" alt="Logotipo Gyga">
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#navigation {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#right-poly{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    right: 0px;
}

#left-poly{
    padding-top: 5%;
    left: 0px;
}
```

It works but I don't know if there is a better way, also, for mobile how can I make these images responsive?

Comment: Use media queries to specify CSS code for various device/viewport screen widths/heights and orientations https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to make images responsive to device display size, you might consider using `vh` and `vw` css units that are relative to device viewport instead of `%`, which are relative to the parent element. It really depends on what you are willing to achieve. Btw, are you using bootstrap or any framework like bootstrap? Those usually come with several options for making your content responsive.

Comment: You could peek this article for better understand about css units: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp